# App links was not worked , using of App link package Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deep-linking, applinks

In my Flutter app , implemented app links support so used app_links: ^3.4.5 package and modified android manifest files and changed in main file as per the documentation .

so , it works in IOS platform but in android whenever i'm click links it directly open browser not opened my app.

Note .. (assetlink.json file was posted in my website).

can you please give any suggestions ..

Comment: Did you add your SHA256 key in assetlink.json

Comment: yes added SHA 256 properly, and i check this https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json with my custom site it shows json data correctly